# How to make a tikz picture appear on every page of document

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am relatively new to Latex and I am struggeling with the use
of the tikzpicture package.

What I want to do is to create a coloured column on the left side of every page in my document. Curently I am using the following code for this.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that this code only produces a coloured bar on the first page of my document and does not extend it to multiple pages.

My question is therefore, how do i implement this tikzpicture to multiple pages in my document?. Does anyone have any insights on how to tackle this problem.

Note: I am not trying to make a header or footer.

Kind regards.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of the `eso-pic` package?

Comment: Hello, No I am not aware of that package. However I will look into it now that you mention it. Thank you

Comment: Or perhaps easier, the `background` package or the `tikzpagenodes` package.  See e.g. [Getting a particular kind of page border using background package](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/113597)

Comment: Welcome! Please, **always** provide a Minimal Working Example ([↗MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Package `atbegshi` is an option for inserting material on every page at an absolute position.
- Package `xsavebox` helps reducing the final PDF size when repeatedly inserting the same content.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xsavebox} %save content for repeated use
\usepackage{atbegshi} %insert material on every page

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %bla, bla

\xsavebox{PageBGPicture}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle, fill=yellow, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight] (box) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%position background picture absolutely (w.r.t. upper left page corner) on every page
\AtBeginShipout{
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\xusebox{PageBGPicture}}}
}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello AlexG, Thanks this work with some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I would also need to change then the picture on every page. I mean, for the first chapter I want to use a certain picture. For the 2nd chapter another picture, and so on. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, something using `eso-pic`. Node that I made your node names unique by adding the page number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
 \AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node [rectangle, fill=blue, anchor=west, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] 
 (box\thepage) at 
 (current page text area.west){};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the atbegshi package.

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```